# Positionning Issue in IE 11 compatiblity view

Tags: html, css, css-position, internet-explorer-11

I have an issue with positionning in css when the code is rendered in IE 11 compatibility view. Same code shows up fine in Chrome and Firefox. Note that when compatibilty view is disabled the whole thing shows up fine.

Basically i have a rectangle that contains a list of "nodes" that have to show up next to one another from left to right.

When in IE 11 compatiblity view mode, the "nodes" inside the main div look like FIXED and will stay in place when scrolling. When not in compatibility view they will behave correctly and always display within the parent div. Note that the main div itself will always appear at the right place, only the content will appear fixed.

Here is what the code looks like ;

```
<!-- This is the main div ---><div id='xxxxx'  style='background-color:#fff;width:100%;height:34px;border:black 1px solid;border-bottom:1px #E0E0E0 solid;padding:5px;' >
<div title='Node1' align ='center' style='left:0px;position:relative;top:0px;line-height:40px;display:inline;height:40px;width:100px;'>Some text</div>

<div title='Node2' align ='center' style='left:-10px;position:relative;top:0px;line-height:40px;display:inline;height:40px;width:100px;'>Some text</div>

<div title='Node3' align ='center' style='left:-20px;position:relative;top:0px;line-height:40px;display:inline;height:40px;width:100px;'>Some text</div>

</div> <!-- end the main div -->
```

As you can see : the main div has no "position" attribute defined
The "nodes" div's inside have relative position defined.
If you notice, the left positionning goes down 10px each time because the "nodes" are overlapping one on each other (which is wanted)

I have little control on what is before and after this code because this is a customization of an existing software and I can only change this part.

I am curious as what do I need to change in order for the inner div to behave the same in compatiblity view.

Comment: Can you put together a live example that illustrates the behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If you would have control over the head section, try putting this in it, as the first tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

That should force IE8+ in its own mode, should override the user-set Compatibility View when the page is (re)loaded.

Comment: This works well.

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility view is not 'compatibility view for ie11' it is ie 11 emulating an older version of ie. If you make it look good for ie7, then it will work.

Here is what it is for-- if your web site looks bad on ie11 then you switch to compatibility view which means 'see if this web site is compatible with an older version of ie instead of ie11' - so it is not generally recommended to plan for that. It is meant as a backup plan if the right format doesn't work right.

The code for old-ie is different for inline-block.

try using this at the end of your css...

```
display:inline-block; *display:inline; *zoom:1;
```

this will target pretty much any version of web browser:

```
style='left:-10px;position:relative;top:0px;line-height:40px;height:40px;width:100px;display:inline-block; *display:inline; *zoom:1;'>Some text</div>
```

You will need to fix the inline-block portion like that for every div, or any place you have an inline-block in your code for it to work right.

The complete code after editing:

```
<!-- This is the main div ---> <div id='xxxxx'  style='background-color:#fff;width:100%;height:34px;border:black 1px solid;border-bottom:1px #E0E0E0 solid;padding:5px;' >

<div title='Node1' align ='center' style='left:0px;position:relative;top:0px;line-height:40px;height:40px;width:100px;display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;'>Some text</div>

<div title='Node2' align ='center' style='left:-10px;position:relative;top:0px;line-height:40px;height:40px;width:100px;display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;'>Some text</div>

<div title='Node3' align ='center' style='left:-20px;position:relative;top:0px;line-height:40px;height:40px;width:100px;display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;'>Some text</div>

</div> <!-- end the main div -->
```

If IE had used the same command for inline-block for every IE version, this would not have been necessary. I tested this for you in compatibility mode before posting and it does work.

It may be to your advantage in the future to instead use a class for this like so:

```
.inline_block { display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1; }
```

Now you can do this:

```
<div class="inline_block" style="STYLES HERE"> Text </div>
```

And your inline blocks will work for everything.

Comment: I totally agree with you ; however the site is actually a web based software I am doing customization on. And the hundreds of users for the customer are all using the same laptop "image" with IE 11 and... compatibility view enabled. This is why i am trying to find a solution.

Comment: The inline-block rewrite I just gave you... the * is for older ie, and the zoom:1 forces it to be in the right rendering mode.